# Rabbits, Rabbits, Rabbits project with new file in python(cs1400)

Tags: python

I created the new file, but I don't know how to use "while loop" to put Fibonacci sequence in the new file. I uploaded the my code1,2 , description, expected output, and data file that I used. I want you to tell me how to write the code. If my code is wrong, I'd appreciate it if you could make it

[discription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jbrq.png)  [expected out put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Yw96.png)   [data file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cxkpq.png)    [first code&comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIIvd.jpg)

Comment: Please post code as text, not as images.

Comment: Post your code…

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere in the code where you defined cages, other then as a parameter. You need to define cages.